# Angular Karma Testing $.cookie

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, karma-jasmine, angular-cookies

My logout function sends a request to the logout api and clears all cookies effectively ending the session. It works really well but when I run the function in test, I get:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

I know this comes from when, in the logout function, I try to clear all of my cookies by running:

```
for(var cookie in $.cookie()) {
    $.removeCookie(cookie);
}
```

Thanks for taking a look! The rest of the code is below:

Controller

```
simulatorApp.controller('homeController', function homeController($scope, $http, $cookies, localAPI) {
$scope.logout = function() {
    var logoutRequest = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: localAPI.url + 'auth/logout/',
        headers: requestHeaders
    };
    $http(logoutRequest);
    for(var cookie in $.cookie()) {
        $.removeCookie(cookie);
    }
};
```

Test

```
describe('homeController', function() {
    beforeEach(module('simulatorApp'));

    var controller;
    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_) {
        controller = _$controller_;
    }));

    var $scope = {};
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $httpBackend) {
        $httpBackend.whenPOST("http://0.0.0.0:8000/api/logout/").respond("Good for you");
        controller('homeController', {
            $scope: $scope
        });
        $scope.logout();
        $httpBackend.flush()
    }));
});
```

Comment: it seems you didn't inject jquery into your test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ is JQuery's keyword, so the problem here your karma runtime have no idea what $ is.

Adding your jquery source in `karma.conf.js`'s file section would solve this issue.

Comment: Good call! Thank you!